# Jquery UI slider disable part

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I need an Jquery UI slider that has an range from 0 till 100 and where the handle is max 75. So the part 75 till 100 is visible in the slider but the handle goes max to 75.

is that possible with Jquery Ui slider?

```
 $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    range: true,
    values: [ 1, 75 ],
    range: "max",
    min: 1,
    max: 100        
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
$('#slider-vertical').slider({
    values: [1, 100],
    range: true,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.value > 75 && ui.value <= 100){
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there any way you can hightlight the available part?